# Rails pass parameter from one controller action to another through form of different object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I need to pass a  parameter from one controller action to another through a form. The action sending the param, `edit`, simply renders the edit page and has no redirect. However I need this parameter in the `update` action. I figured I could use a hidden field:

`f.hidden_field :route_id, value: @route.id`

but since the attribute doesn't belong to the same object the form is for I get `unknown attribute 'route_id'`

Any suggestions?

Edit: More info. So what we're looking at in this edit action is a `BusStop`. An important thing to note is that there are two ways to get to `BusStop`, either by searching via name or via a list of stops on a `Route`. Now, what I'm trying to do for the convenience of the user is have a "Save and next" button, but we only want that option if the stop is reached through the route's list. That is submit the form and redirect to the next `BusStop`. However, in order to find the next `BusStop` we need two things. A `Route.id` and a `BusStopsRoute.direction`. `BusStopsRoutes` have two directions, and a `BusStop` may or may not be in both directions, so we cannot infer direction by stop. Similarly we cannot infer the `Route` by the `BusStop` because `BusStop` and `Route` have a many-to-many relationship through `BusStopsRoute`.

Bringing it back a bit, I have the values of `Route.id` and `BusStopsRoute.direction` in the `BusStop` edit action. I need those values in the `BusStop` update action to find the next `BusStop`.

Comment: A hidden field is a reasonable idea. That thing you have isn't a hidden field. Take a look at [hidden_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag).

Comment: can you add more info about what are you trying to do with that parameter? maybe to give you more specific idea. another option that you have, if your form is on post mode, then you can add the parameter on the url of the form action

Comment: @jvillian shoot you're right. I was using a hidden field, I just changed it to a text field to ensure the value was actually present. I copied and pasted the line here and forgot to change it back. My bad.

Comment: `f.hidden_field` still not working for you? (Seems like it shouldn't.) Did you try `hidden_field_tag`?

Comment: @jvillian Oh. I didn't realize you could use `hidden_field_tag` in an `form_for`. Yeah that solves my problem. Please create an answer so I can mark it as correct, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this:

```
f.hidden_field :route_id, value: @route.id
```

when you want to create a hidden field from an attribute on the model represented by `f`.

Since you're trying to create a hidden field for a value that is not an attribute on the model represented by `f`, use `hidden_field_tag`, something like:

```
hidden_field_tag :route_id, @route.id
```

For more information, see the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag).

Answer (score -2):

You can use [ActiveModel::Attributes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#attribute-methods) API.

In this object's class,

```
class Voxorin < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :route_id
end
```

Assuming your object is an ActiveRecord object you don't need to include the modules.

You could also use `attr_accessor` or write your getter/setter yourself, but you lose all the methods that surround attributes that you're used to — like DirtyMethods (route_id_changed?) and coercion.